# How can i, set the max & min value for React form input type="date"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input

This is my code for the input box of type date -

```
<label htmlFor="invoiceDate">Invoice Date</label>
                      <input
                        type="date"
                        name="invoiceDate"
                        id="invoiceDate"
                        placeholder="Invoice Date"
                        autoComplete="off"                            
                        value={invoicedate}
                        onChange={(e) =>setInvoicedate(e.target.value)}
                      />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type='date' min="2019-01-02" max='2023-01-02' />
```